# How to print a list of strings in a specific manner?

Tags: python, string, list

A list of strings is given to me and I have to print their elements in a specific manner.

suppose, `L = ['RED', 'GREEN', 'BLUE']`

and the output is supposed to be, `R G B E R L D E U E E N`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can probably be done with a nested while-for loop. Something like

```
length_of_longest_string = 0
for s in L:
    length_of_longest_string = max(len(s), length_of_longest_string)

i = 0
result_string = ""
while i < length_of_longest_string:
    for s in L:
        if i >= len(s):
            continue
        else:
            result_string += s[i] + " "
    i += 1

print(result_string)
```

where you just find the length of the longest string using the initial for loop.

Answer (score 1):

A simple for loop will do the job.

```
L = ['RED', 'GREEN', 'BLUE']

s = ''
for i in range(max([len(x) for x in L])): #len of longest word in L
    for item in L:
        try:
            s += item[i] + ' '
        except IndexError:
            pass

print(s)

R G B E R L D E U E E N
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses some advanced concepts, but it's neat and tidy:

```
from itertools import zip_longest, chain
L = ['RED', 'GREEN', 'BLUE']
print(''.join(chain(*zip_longest(*L, fillvalue=''))))
# 'RGBERLDEUEEN'
```

To include spaces between the letters, you can do this instead:

```
' '.join(''.join(chain(*zip_longest(*L, fillvalue=''))))
# R G B E R L D E U E E N
```

Comment: Nice one! It's missing the spaces though.

Comment: Ok, they're in there now!

Comment: I have never worked with itertools so a little hard to understand. But it works Thanks @MatthiasFripp

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `itertools`:

```
from itertools import chain, zip_longest

l = ['RED', 'GREEN', 'BLUE']
print(*filter(bool, chain(*zip_longest(*l))))
```